# How to load array from web service for searching in uitextfield?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I wish to send an array of say stationNames in a SOAP call .
Please help.

This code for manual input to array

```
  - (void)autoCompleteTextField:(MLPAutoCompleteTextField *)textField
  possibleCompletionsForString:(NSString *)string
         completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))handler
   {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    if(self.simulateLatency){
        CGFloat seconds = arc4random_uniform(4)+arc4random_uniform(4); //normal distribution
        NSLog(@"sleeping fetch of completions for %f", seconds);
        sleep(seconds);
    }

    NSArray *completions;
    if(self.testWithAutoCompleteObjectsInsteadOfStrings){
        completions = [self allCountryObjects];
    } else {
        completions = [self allCountries];
    }

    handler(completions);
});
}


 - (NSArray *)allCountryObjects
  {
if(!self.countryObjects){
    NSArray *countryNames = [self allCountries];
    NSMutableArray *mutableCountries = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(NSString *countryName in countryNames){
        DEMOCustomAutoCompleteObject *country = [[DEMOCustomAutoCompleteObject alloc] initWithCountry:countryName];
        [mutableCountries addObject:country];
    }

    [self setCountryObjects:[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableCountries]];
}

return self.countryObjects;
 }


   - (NSArray *)allCountries
  {
NSArray *countries =
@[
  @"Item1",
  @"Item2",
  @"Item3",
  @"Item4",
  @"Item5",
  @"Item6",
  @"Item7",
  @"Item8",
  @"Item9",
  ];

return countries;
 }


  - (BOOL)autoCompleteTextField:(MLPAutoCompleteTextField *)textField
      shouldConfigureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
   withAutoCompleteString:(NSString *)autocompleteString
     withAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)boldedString
    forAutoCompleteObject:(id<MLPAutoCompletionObject>)autocompleteObject
        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;


       //This is your chance to customize an autocomplete tableview cell before it appears 
 in the autocomplete tableview
       NSString *filename = [autocompleteString stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
       filename = [filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"];
       filename = [filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and"];
       [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:filename]];

      return YES;

 }

     - (void)autoCompleteTextField:(MLPAutoCompleteTextField *)textField
     didSelectAutoCompleteString:(NSString *)selectedString
     withAutoCompleteObject:(id<MLPAutoCompletionObject>)selectedObject
     forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
   if(selectedObject){
    NSLog(@"selected object from autocomplete menu %@ with string %@", selectedObject,    
 [selectedObject autocompleteString]);
   } else {
    NSLog(@"selected string '%@' from autocomplete menu", selectedString);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Pls clarify what you want to do . Upload an array in a Soap call or download something ?

Comment: @AbhishekBedi I see all fields of station name on NSLog.I want load all station name to in array like at top sample ?

Comment: Load all station names ??? you mean that you want to filter the log for station names and save it ito an array?

Comment: I have station name element in web service.Yes I mean save to array for listing in textfield

Comment: hi @Mhmt any solution found to this...even i want to pass an array from my webservice data...